# How to update multiple rows from database in one query using codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, activerecord

I just want to ask how to update multiple rows in one query. I can only insert multiple data in a row using the insert_batch function but I couldn't find it works in update batch. I don't know how to do it. I have already searched on google on how to make it but I have no luck. Your answer is very much appreciated.

I have two tables **'questionnaire'** and **'choices'**

table info. for **questionnaire** table

> -questionnaire_id
>
> -type_id_fk
>
> -question
>
> -answer

table info. for **choices** table

> -choices_id
>
> -questionnaire_id_fk
>
> -choices

**My Controller**

```
public function update_selectedQuestionnaire() {
      $this->test_model->update_questionnaire();
      redirect('test/questionnaire', 'refresh');
}
```

**My Model**

```
    function update_questionnaire() {

            $Qid = $this->input->post('Qid'); //questionnaire id
            $Cid = $this->input->post('Cid'); //questionnaire id
            $type = $this->input->post('type');
            $question = $this->db->escape_like_str($this->input->post('question'));
            $answer = $this->db->escape_like_str($this->input->post('answer'));

            $choice1 = $this->db->escape_like_str($this->input->post('choice1'));
            $choice2 = $this->db->escape_like_str($this->input->post('choice2'));
            $choice3 = $this->db->escape_like_str($this->input->post('choice3'));
            $choice4 = $this->db->escape_like_str($this->input->post('choice4'));


       $Cdata = array(
            array(
                'choices_id' => $Cid,
                'questionnaire_id_fk' => $Qid,
                'choices' => $choice1
            ),
            array(
                'choices_id' => $Cid,
                'questionnaire_id_fk' => $Qid,
                'choices' => $choice2
            ),
            array(
                'choices_id' => $Cid,
                'questionnaire_id_fk' => $Qid,
                'choices' => $choice3
            ),
            array(
                'choices_id' => $Cid,
                'questionnaire_id_fk' => $Qid,
                'choices' => $choice4
            )
        );

        $this->db->trans_start();
        $this->db->query("UPDATE questionnaire SET type_id_fk=$type, question='$question', answer='$answer' WHERE questionnaire_id=$Qid");
        $this->db->update_batch('choices', $Cdata, 'choices_id');
        var_dump($Cdata);
        $this->db->trans_complete();

    }
```

**My view**

```
<div class="jumbotron">
        <div class=" col-md-9 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 panel-body">
            <h3>Update Questionnaire</h3>
            <?php echo form_open('test/update_selectedQuestionnaire'); ?>
            <?php
            foreach ($query as $row): echo '<input type="hidden" name="Qid" id="Qid" value="' . $row->questionnaire_id . '"/><br />';
            endforeach;
            foreach ($choices as $row): echo '<input type="hidden" name="Cid" id="Cid" value="' . $row->choices_id . '"/>';
            endforeach;
            ?>
            <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-2"><label>Type:</label></div><div class="col-md-10">
                <?php
                echo '<select name="type" id="type" required class="form-control">';
                echo '<option value=""></option>';
                foreach ($type as $tRow):
                    echo '<option value="' . $tRow->type_id . '"';
                    foreach ($query as $qRow):
                        if ($tRow->type_id === $qRow->type_id_fk):
                            echo 'selected';
                        endif;
                    endforeach;
                    echo '>' . $tRow->type . '</option>';
                endforeach;
                echo '</select>';
                ?>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-2"><label>Question:</label></div><div class="col-md-10">
                <?php
                foreach ($query as $row): echo '<input type="text" name="question" id="question" value="' . $row->question . '" required class="form-control"/>';
                endforeach;
                ?>
            </div>
            <div class="jumbotron">

                <?php
                $i = 0;
                foreach ($choices as $row): $i++;
                    echo '<div class="col-md-2 col-sm-2"><label>Choice ' . $i . ':</label></div><div class="col-md-9"><div class="col-md-11 col-sm-11 col-xs-11">'
                    . '<input type="text" name="choices" id="choice_' . $row->choices_id . '" value="' . $row->choices . '" class="form-control"/>'
                    . '</div><div class="col-md-1 col-sm-1 col-xs-1"><a class="label label-warning" hef="#" id="setAns_' . $row->choices_id . '">set</a></div></div>';
                endforeach;
                ?>
                <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-2"><label>Answer:</label></div><div class="col-md-10">
                    <?php
                    foreach ($query as $row): echo '<input type="text" name="answer" id="answer" value="' . $row->answer . '" required class="form-control" readonly/>';
                    endforeach;
                    ?>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="panel-body">
            <div class="text-center col-md-9 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                <hr />
                <button type="button" onclick="goBack()" class="btn btn-default">Cancel</button>
                <button type="submit" name="update" class="btn btn-primary">Update</button>
            </div>
        </div>
        <?php form_close(); ?>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For multiple update you can use `$this->db->update_batch`

```
     $Cdata = array(
                array(
                    'choices_id' => $Cid,
                    'questionnaire_id_fk' => $Qid,
                    'choices' => $choice1
                ),
                array(
                    'choices_id' => $Cid,
                    'questionnaire_id_fk' => $Qid,
                    'choices' => $choice2
                ),
                array(
                    'choices_id' => $Cid,
                    'questionnaire_id_fk' => $Qid,
                    'choices' => $choice3
                ),
                array(
                    'choices_id' => $Cid,
                    'questionnaire_id_fk' => $Qid,
                    'choices' => $choice4
                )
            );

$this->db->update_batch('choices', $Cdata, 'choices_id');
```

Comment: Thank you so much for @Saty for your answer. However I've tried it already I don't know why it's not working. Maybe I missed something.

Comment: that's the only solution for multiple upload in CI.Plsese check your column name it is correct or not

Comment: check this [link](http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/query_builder.html)

Comment: Thanks for it.
I made a var_dump and this is the result.

array(4) { [0]=> array(3) { ["choices_id"]=> string(1) "4" ["questionnaire_id_fk"]=> string(1) "1" ["choices"]=> string(0) "" } [1]=> array(3) { ["choices_id"]=> string(1) "4" ["questionnaire_id_fk"]=> string(1) "1" ["choices"]=> string(0) "" } [2]=> array(3) { ["choices_id"]=> string(1) "4" ["questionnaire_id_fk"]=> string(1) "1" ["choices"]=> string(0) "" } [3]=> array(3) { ["choices_id"]=> string(1) "4" ["questionnaire_id_fk"]=> string(1) "1" ["choices"]=> string(0) "" } }

Comment: what i see your `choices` in empty in all

Comment: i think problem is with `choices` your data is not set.

Comment: In my view I have this code:
<?php
                $i = 0;
                foreach ($choices as $row): $i++;
                    <input type="text" name="choice'.$i.'" id="choice_' . $row->choices_id . '" value="' . $row->choices . '" class="form-control"/>
                endforeach;
                ?>

Comment: print_r($_POST) in your controller and paste the result of it

Comment: check your choice name is `name="choice'.$i.'" ` or not

Comment: Here's the result of it. 
Array ( [Qid] => 1 [Cid] => 4 [type] => 2 [question] => First question [choice1] => a1 [choice2] => b2 [choice3] => c3 [choice4] => d4 [answer] => d4 [update] => ) 1Array ( [Qid] => 1 [Cid] => 4 [type] => 2 [question] => First question [choice1] => a1 [choice2] => b2 [choice3] => c3 [choice4] => d4 [answer] => d4 [update] => )

Comment: It seems that only the last row is being updated and the rest is not.

Comment: I see, so I what I need to change?

Comment: echo '<input type="hidden" name="Cid$i" id="Cid" value="' . $row->choices_id . '"/>';

Comment: Please help me with this. I am really new at this. Your help is very much appreciated.

Comment: I've change it already. Do I need to change or add something in the model?

Comment: `$Cid1 = $this->input->post('Cid1');$Cid2= $this->input->post('Cid2');...`. in controller

Comment: It's working already!!! Thank you  so much for your help! I really appreciate your help. :)
I just assign a variable in each name: 
$Cid1 = $this->input->post('Cid1');
        $Cid2 = $this->input->post('Cid2');
        $Cid3 = $this->input->post('Cid3');
        $Cid4 = $this->input->post('Cid4');